Who said "If you don't do politics, politics will do you"?
There is a quote, "If you don't do politics, politics will do you."
Who said it? Google says that it's either Pericles or Bismarck, but neither of Wikiquote's pages for them includes this.

Sounds like one of those "In Mother Russia" style jokes.

Possibly modeled on this quote by Leon Trotsky:  “You may not be interested in war, but war is interested in you.”

The Pericles quote is here and he's saying that people uninterested in politics are useless for society: https://www.uvm.edu/~jbailly/courses/clas158/etexts/funeralOrationText.html.

TL;DR: The author of the quote is Charles de Montalembert, who said it sometime prior to 1870.

The first mention of the quote was in French, published in a letter from December 18th 1871 by Ximénès Doudan to Mademoiselle Gavard (as per this book it was Élise-Thérèse Gavard, daughter of Charles Gavard):

Oserai-je vous demander, mademoiselle, pourquoi vous avez renoncé soudainement à la politique? C'est pourtant bien le moment de lui porter quelque intérêt. La pauvre dame n'est pas dans une grande prospérité, et puis il a été dit avec justesse (je crois par un parent de M. W. de Mérode : « Vous avez beau ne pas vous occuper de politique, la politique s'occupe de vous tout de même, » et une femme, au général Bonaparte, qui disait rudement qu'il n'aimait pas que les femmes se mêlassent de politique : « Quand on coupe la tête aux femmes, il est assez naturel qu'elles veuillent savoir pourquoi. » Or, il n'y a pas plus de six mois que la Commune donnait fort à songer aux dames.

Which can be translated to:

Dare I ask you, mademoiselle, why you suddenly gave up on politics? It is certainly the time to take some interest in it. The poor lady is not in great prosperity, and then it has been rightly said (I believe by a relative of Mr. W. de Mérode): "You may not care about politics, but politics still cares about you," and a woman, to General Bonaparte, who rudely said he didn't like women meddling in politics: "When women have their heads cut off, it is but just they should know the reason." After all, it’s only been six months since the Commune gave the ladies much to think about.

Prof. Othon Guerlac writing in a 1920 book titled "L'intermédiaire des chercheurs et curieux" suggests that this "relative of Mr. W. de Mérode" was Count Montalembert (1810-1870). Therefore "Mr. W. de Mérode" was Werner de Merode, who's sister married Montalembert. Lastly, the quote about women in politics was first published in 1818 in Madame de Staël's posthumous book about the French revolution.

« Vous avez beau ne pas vous occuper de politique...» (LXXX,288}. — Cette phrase a été prononcée par Montalembert, beau-frère du comte Werner de Mérode, dont il avait épousé la sœur.


"You may not care about politics..." (LXXX, 288). — This phrase was spoken by Montalembert, brother-in-law of Count Werner de Mérode, whose sister he had married.

Here "LXXX,288" refers to a previous volume of the same book where a curious reader asks:

« Vous avez beau ne pas vous occuper de politique... » — Dans une
lettre du 16 décembre 1871 adressée à Mlle Gavard, Doudan écrit :
Il a été dit avec justesse par un parent de W. de Mérode : « Vous avez
beau ne pas vous occuper de politique, la politique s’occupe de vous
tout de même. »
Peut-on nous dire qui est ce « parent de W. de Mérode » et où il a
exprimé ce sentiment ?


"You may not care about politics..." — In a letter dated December 16, 1871, addressed to Mademoiselle Gavard, Doudan wrote:
It was rightly said by a relative of W. de Mérode: "You may not care about politics, but politics still cares about you."
Can anyone tell us who this "relative of W. de Mérode" is and where this sentiment was expressed?

The first version I can find in English is from the Muncie Evening Press published in 1916:

It used to be that the best government was the least government. That was all right when it took you six weeks to go from Cincinnati to Baltimore by stage. Today it is different. Now, then if any one here is not interested in politics today, get interested because politics is interested in you. It is essential that politics be in every home.


I'm a bit confused by the dates here. I would expect "the Commune" to refer to the Commune of Paris, 1870-1871, and General Bonaparte to refer to Napoleon Bonaparte, who died in 1821. Napoleon III was in power circa 1870, but I would be surprised to see him referred to as general. (Excellent quote otherwise)

@MatthieuM. My understanding is that this refers to Napoleon Bonaparte, the two quotes "by a relative of Mr. W. de Mérode" and by "a woman" don't need to be contemporary... Although Napoleon III was indeed a general, schooled in the military school of Thoune, and portrayed in general uniform in 1862 (https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Napol%C3%A9on_III#/media/Fichier:Napol%C3%A9on_III_par_Jean_Hippolyte_Flandrin.jpg).

@MatthieuM. he tries to convince Mademoiselle Gavard to start caring about politics using three arguments: 1) The Montalembert quote 2) An anecdote about a woman supposedly confronting Napoleon Bonaparte back in the day 3) (then) recent events of the Paris Commune.

The specific form of this phrase quoted, using "to do" meaning "to injure", seems quite contemporary. The phrase does not get any hits on google ngrams, which further leads me to suppose that it is a fairly recent coinage. It seems to be generally attributed to the South African writer Christina Engela, and indeed on LitNet, Engela recounts the following anecdote:

On Saturday I was at a canvassing table in my voting district, asking
people to sign a petition against the government’s proposed new
legislation which will gag the media...
"I don't do politics," one smart-looking dude told me. "But politics will do you!" I replied, while he and his girlfriend stared at me as
though I were from another planet.

The posting is dated as the 26th August 2010. Unless someone can identify an earlier occurrence of the phrase, this seems a convincing candidate for its origin.

I'm not sure where you're getting your dismissal of non-English interpretations from. Any language with a clearly subject/object grammar is going to convey the different meaning from swapping them around. The independent definition of "do" meaning "hurt" is not particularly relevant to convey the overall meaning of the saying, i.e. that one's interaction with politics, or more importantly their lack thereof, does not prevent politics from interacting with them.

@Flater The OP is specifically asking about a form of the quote using "to do". As far as I know (though willing to be corrected!)  the only language that uses "to do" in this way is English, indicating that the originator of this specific form of the quote is probably an English speaker.

This totally works in Russian (usind the verb заниматься), and I've heard the quote a lot.

@svavil Fair enough, I've taken that claim out. Do you want to write an answer about the Russian usage?

@ClaraDíazSanchez: The usage of the verb "to do" (or any word, for that matter) does not mean that every possible definition of the word should be simultaneously carried over when translating. The cliche "In Mother Russia" style jokes prove that inversion of subject/object generally implies an inversion in the agency of who affects whom, which is the core focus of the witticism. It does not hinge on a specific definition of a single word specifically in English.

You're basing your argument on the English definition of "to do" meaning "to injure", but you provide no evidence that this is the specific definition that whoever coined the phrase was aiming for in the first place. I'm not implying it definitely doesn't find its roots in English, I'm just disagreeing with your reasoning for excluding other possible sources.

This is possibly a misremembered quote from The Politics of Authenticity: Radical Individualism and the Emergence of Modern Society (1970) by the American philosopher Marshall Berman (1940–2013). The quote comes from the book's last sentence and goes as follows (emphasis mine):

whoever you are, or want to be, you may not be interested in politics, but politics is interested in you.

It is a parody of a quote often attributed to Leon Trotsky that goes as follows:

You may not be interested in war, but war is interested in you.

This is also how people writing about Berman often present it. For example, Todd Gitlin's article Marshall Berman, author of 'All that is solid...", is no more (18 September 2013):

“Whoever you are or want to be,” he wrote at the end of that book, paraphrasing Trotsky, “you may not be interested in politics, but politics is interested in you.”

However, JonathanReez pointed out in a comment that the words can also be found in a publication from 1931 (emphasis mine):

Says Charles J. Whalen, editor of the Illinois Medical Journal, "Length and strength of governmental control in public and private affairs is a menacing scourge confronting the American people. Nowhere does this invidious paternalism make itself more insidiously apparent than in the question of medical economics." You may not be interested in politics, but politics is interested in you.

The source is E. L. Jewell's "Presidential Address" to the Wyoming State Medical Society on 13 July 1931, reprinted in the October 1931 issue of Colorado Medicine.
